# jBPM Runtime Strategy and Timer Events

Tags: jbpm, bpmn

Details:

- BPMN Version: 2
- jBPM Version: 6.5
- Java Version: 8
- Container: Tomcat, SpringBoot

We have a BPMN process definition that includes a timer event.  We've changed the runtime strategy from **singleton** to **per_request** to allow for more process instances to run simultaneously.  Testing has been successful so far, but I'm not sure if we've covered timing issues properly.

Are there any caveats to using a per_request strategy with timer events?  What should we look out for?

This article seems to suggest there are complications, but doesn't delve into details:
https://karinavarela.me/2020/06/16/runtime-strategy-choose-wisely/

Answer (score 0):

Per Request Strategy: This runtime strategy is based on a stateless behavior. The runtime engine will create a Kie Session per request and destroy it when the request is completed. The Kie Session will not be persisted. This strategy is ideal to scale high workload processes however it can make your implementation more complex.

**Per Process Instance Strategy**: in this runtime strategy a KieSession is created when a Process Instance is created. The Process instance is finalized when the Process ends.

The runtime manager maintains mapping between process instance and KieSession and always provides same KieSession whenever working with given process instance

This strategy works well in most cases, however it is recommended if your process are based on Business Rule Tasks and Timers.